# Merge json in nifi with JoltTransform

Tags: json, merge, apache-nifi

I would like to merge two different json in nifi.
first json comes from an attribute to json processor and contains just an id, something like:

```
 {
    "id": "1234"
 }
```

second one is a json of this structure:

```
[
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"}
]
```

desired result should be something like:

```
{
"id": "1234",
"data": [
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"},
{"id1": "1234","id2": "1234","id3": "1234"}
]
}
```

how can I make it? I was trying merge content to concatenate those two json flowfiles having this result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1233"
  },
  [
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    }
  ]
]
```

now, I think I need a Jolt transform but I don't know which are the parameters of the transformation...

Comment: and so what I have to do?

Comment: I couldn't understand the correlation between question and  the provided answer ...

Comment: my answer is a transformation that I tested with the previous json on joltdemo and it does what I expect but when I put that string in nifi jolttransform processor does not work....maybe there is something wrong but I don't understand what

Comment: what JSON input did you use within the joltdemo ?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "1233"
  },
  [
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id1": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    }
  ]
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235387/discussion-between-alexmark-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Answer (score 0):

I found out this solution but when I apply it on nifi it returns an error saying
**" is invalid because specification not valid for the selected transformation**

but it works on jolttransformation demo (https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "&",
        "*": "result"
    }
  }
]
```

I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose transformation type Chain with your JOLT specification and it will work