# Regex to extract fields in json NiFi

Tags: json, regex, apache-nifi

Beginner RegExp question. I have a JSON in my NiFi ExtractText and there are 2 fields I want to extract. How would I use a regex to do this?

```
[
  {
    "id": "12erf3-312331-233"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "1234"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "id2": "1234",
      "id3": "5555"
    }
  ]
]
```

1. get the first id: "12erf3-312331-233" (this is a uuid)
2. get all the second array: [ { "id": "1234" ... "id3": "5555" } ]

Comment: did you try to use JoltTransformJSON processor ?

Comment: Yes….but there was an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548184/merge-json-in-nifi-with-jolttransform…I’m trying another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you need you may use ReplaceText processor. Have a look to the configuration below. Search Value would be `(?s).*("id": )(".*").*}.*(\[.*\]).*\]` and the Replacement Value: `{$1$2,data:$3}`. Pay attention to pick Evaluation Mode as "Entire text".
To easily check regex you can use link i have used: https://regex101.com/r/p6T2Vw/1

[image]

Comment: sure. hope it helps